# How to submit multiple responses at the same time (questionnaire tool)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this questionnaire tool I was working on which displayed one question at a time (picked from a drop down menu) and you can choose answer and it will update db with the option chosen when the submit button is clicked. I now require to have multiple questions on the same page and I am not sure how I can scale my code to do that. I am quite new so sorry if it's a stupid question.

My code for the process is as follows:

```
if($selected_radio == "A") {
            $votedSQL = "UPDATE tangible SET VotedA = VotedA + 1 WHERE ID = ?";
            $voteMessage = insert_vote($db_found, $votedSQL, $idNumber);
        }
        else if($selected_radio == "B"){
            $votedSQL = "UPDATE tangible SET VotedB = VotedB + 1 WHERE ID = ?";
            $voteMessage = insert_vote($db_found, $votedSQL, $idNumber);
        }
        else if($selected_radio == "C"){
            $votedSQL = "UPDATE tangible SET VotedC = VotedC + 1 WHERE ID = ?";
            $voteMessage = insert_vote($db_found, $votedSQL, $idNumber);
        }
        else if($selected_radio == "D"){
            $votedSQL = "UPDATE tangible SET VotedD = VotedD + 1 WHERE ID = ?";
            $voteMessage = insert_vote($db_found, $votedSQL, $idNumber);
        }
        else {
    error messages
```

with this to insert vote into db:

```
function insert_vote($db, $sql, $id) {

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

I track who has voted by using the url:

```
if (isset($_GET['h1'])) {
    $qID = $_GET['h1'];
} else {
    $qID = 1;
}
```

Please let me know if you need anything else and I appreciate the any help in advance!

Comment: I don't think you should do it like that. A "field = field + 1" should only be used, if you have one counter. In your case I would insert the answer and then count it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could certainly do some simplification by:

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-D]$/', $selected_radio)) {
    $votedSQL = "UPDATE tangible SET Voted{$selected_radio} = Voted{$selected_radio} + 1 WHERE ID = ?";
    $voteMessage = insert_vote($db_found, $votedSQL, $idNumber);
} else // error handling
```

I feel sure there are other optimizations you could do, but this at least reduces one headache.

Comment: I think he should do something like:

<input name="q1[]" type="radio" value="A">
<input name="q1[]" type="radio" value="B">

$answer = $_POST["q1"]; // A or B

Instead. That also takes care of multiple questions.

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle No doubt.  Without seeing the form, it's hard to know exactly where to begin.